# Using same submit to Add and Edit to database values in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, postback

I am using a same submit button to Add new row and also edit a row's values of a database table in and ASP.NET form. I use `CommandArgument` to change the method being applied.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!CheckProfileComplete())
        {
            btnSave.CommandArgument = "new";
            btnSave.Text = "Save";
        }
        else
        {
            btnSave.CommandArgument = "update";
            btnSave.Text = "Update";
        }
    }
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;
        string strCmd = this.btnSave.CommandArgument;
        if (strCmd.ToLower() == "new")
        {
             //Add new Record
        }
        else if(strCmd.ToLower() == "update")
        {
             //Update existing record.
        }
     }
```

In case of `Add New` a blank form is presented, while in `Update` a form with previously added data to the database table is presented, where the user can edit the values and then save it. The `CommandArgument` is updated at page load, after checking some other parameters.

The `Add New` method runs fine, but I am unable to edit the values in case of `Update`. I mean the form posts the same values that were dynamically filled before presenting to the user for editing. No change is being shown after the Save (Update mode) button is clicked. It seems like the form takes its previous state as the current state even after values being changed and posted back.

for example if `tbName.Text` had value `foo` when read from database initially.

user edited it, now `tbName.Text` has `bar` before postback.

But when the form is posted while in debug mode, the `tbName.Text` shows `foo` as the current value in place of `bar`

Comment: can you please show me the code of bindData in case of Update.. how you are filling the controls.

Comment: @raman, Adding the same would make the question very long. What I do, is that I query the database for a record, and store the same in a dataset (only 1 row is returned). Now using the table (dt) of the dataset I iterate through the datarow `foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)`, and then populate my controls using `tbName.Text= dr["PName"].ToString()`

Comment: Seems like your code is rebinding data when you try to update your values, SO check if you are using `(!IsPostBack)` while you are populating values for updating , I think that will be in Page_Load event,.

Comment: @Cyberpks DO not worry about long question, Please post your code .

Comment: I just want to know how you are getting the identity column's value against which you are accessing the data from db..

Comment: @SurajSingh, bingo!!! That made it. How could I be so silly? I was not checking the IsPostback, before populating controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine which event it is that occurs which makes you need to change the way the button works.  Once you know that, then, inside that event you unsubscribe the button and subscribe it to something else.

```
private void OnMyEvent()
{
   button1.Click -= "theEventIDoNotWant";
   btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(theEventIWant);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i know it should work something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" CommandArgument="Add" OnCommand="btnSave_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>
```

and code behind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(string.Equals(e.CommandArgument,"Add"))
        {
            //do save logic here
            btnSave.CommandArgument = "Edit";
            btnSave.Text = "Update";
        }

        if (string.Equals(e.CommandArgument, "Edit"))
        {
            //do update logic here
            btnSave.Text = "Update done";
        }   
}
```

you need to implement only one event handler and check what argument you sent with the event using the CommandEventArgs.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers!